# AngularJS - ForEach not looping

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, angularjs, foreach

### Issue

---

I have an AngularJS application and for some reason one of my `forEach` loops are not working. The loop seems to work when the a function on a button click but on the initial load it isn't working.

### Code

---

So I have my controller correctly set up for the page. I am calling a function in my service which fires off to my API and returns me an array:

**Controller**

```
var holidaysnew = getUserEventsById.getUserEventsById();
```

**Service**

```
app.service('getUserEventsById', function ($http) {  

this.getUserEventsById = function () {
    var holidays = [];


    $http.get("http://localhost:9847/AceTracker.svc/GetAllEventsByUser?user_id=1").success(function (data) {
        for (var key in data.GetAllEventsByUserResult) {
            if (data.GetAllEventsByUserResult.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                holidays.push(data.GetAllEventsByUserResult[key])
            }
        }
    });
    return holidays;
};
});
```

So on the initial page load `holidaysnew` gets successfully hit and is an array of the holidays. Below the line is where my `forEach` loop is, I want to loop through `holidaysnew` but it doesn't seem to go into the loop.

The loop is coded as below:

```
holidaysnew.forEach(function (hol) {
    $scope.eventSources[0].events.push({
        end: $filter('dateFilter')(hol.HOLIDAY_END),
        start: $filter('dateFilter')(hol.HOLIDAY_START),
        title: hol.HOLIDAY_TITLE,
        color: $filter('colorEventFilter')(hol.HOLIDAY_EVENT_STATE_ID)
    });
});
```

I have `console.log` the `holidaysnew` array and it definitely getting populated. Can anyone see the issue?

EDIT:

The service seems to be fine and return back the array as expected (*See below*)

[image]

But when the `$scope.eventSources[0].events = holidayEvents;` code gets run it doesn't actually seem to set the events.

Is `holidayEvents` an array?

EDIT2:

Here is a sample of the JSON returned to the service:

```
{"GetAllEventsByUserResult":[{"HOLIDAY_END":"\/Date(1456358400000+0000)\/","HOLIDAY_EVENT_ID":1,"HOLIDAY_EVENT_STATE_ID":1,"HOLIDAY_START":"\/Date(1455926400000+0000)\/","HOLIDAY_TITLE":"Spain     ","USER_ID":1},{"HOLIDAY_END":"\/Date(1454371200000+0000)\/","HOLIDAY_EVENT_ID":2,"HOLIDAY_EVENT_STATE_ID":2,"HOLIDAY_START":"\/Date(1454284800000+0000)\/","HOLIDAY_TITLE":"Italy     ","USER_ID":1},{"HOLIDAY_END":"\/Date(1458000000000+0000)\/","HOLIDAY_EVENT_ID":3,"HOLIDAY_EVENT_STATE_ID":1,"HOLIDAY_START":"\/Date(1457568000000+0000)\/","HOLIDAY_TITLE":"Germany   ","USER_ID":1},{"HOLIDAY_END":"\/Date(1481068800000+0000)\/","HOLIDAY_EVENT_ID":4,"HOLIDAY_EVENT_STATE_ID":3,"HOLIDAY_START":"\/Date(1480896000000+0000)\/","HOLIDAY_TITLE":"England   ","USER_ID":1}]}
```

Comment: `$http` is asynchronous...you can't loop over the returned array until it has been populated

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an error with handling your REST response. The population of the array is happening after the return statement, as the REST call is asynchronous. Try moving the loop that isn't working into it's own function, and then calling that function inside the REST success callback, or return a Promise and resolve it in the success callback.

Returning a promise:

```
app.service('getUserEventsById', function ($http, $q) {  

    this.getUserEventsById = function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var holidays = [];


        $http.get("http://localhost:9847/AceTracker.svc/GetAllEventsByUser?user_id=1").then(function (data) {
            for (var key in data.GetAllEventsByUserResult) {
                if (data.GetAllEventsByUserResult.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    holidays.push(data.GetAllEventsByUserResult[key])
                }
            }
            deferred.resolve(holidays);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    };
});
```

Looping on the promise:

```
holidaysnew.then(function(holidays) {
    holidays.forEach(function (hol) {
        $scope.eventSources[0].events.push({
            end: $filter('dateFilter')(hol.HOLIDAY_END),
            start: $filter('dateFilter')(hol.HOLIDAY_START),
            title: hol.HOLIDAY_TITLE,
            color: $filter('colorEventFilter')(hol.HOLIDAY_EVENT_STATE_ID)
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: there is no `$scope` in a service... use promise for this

Comment: Ah of course - I've changed it to use a callback, but a promise is probably better

Comment: Yes is definitely better, need to consider what happens if request fails there is a complete disconnect at controller which has no way to catch that failure.

Comment: I've added in a version which returns a promise. Untested though, so if you see any glaring errors, let me know and I'll fix!

Comment: Unfortunately that's an anti-pattern. `$http` itself returns  a promise and `success` is deprecated (see docs) in favor of using `then()` promise chain

Comment: Ah hadn't seen that, I was only looking at getting a promise to return at all. I've switched to using `.then` but there would probably need to be error/response handling in there too. I'll save that for another day!

Comment: @millerbr I have added the code to return the promise, but in my controller it has an error : `holidaysnew.foreach` is not a function?

Comment: I've added in code to perform a loop on the result of the promise

Answer (score 1):

Change service to return the `$http` promise but to also to do all the data manipulation you need in the service itself to create the calendar events and return those.

`success` is deprecated in favor of using `then()` promise chain callbacks

A more conventional approach would look like:

```
app.service('getUserEventsById', function($http, $q) {

  this.getUserEventsById = function() {

    var requestPromise = $http.get("url")
      .then(function(response) {
        var holidays = [];
        var results = response.data.GetAllEventsByUserResult
        for (var key in results) {
          if (results.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            holidays.push(results[key])
          }
        }
        // return holidays array to next `then()`
        return holidays;
      }).then(function(holidays) {
        var holidayEvents = holidays.map(function(hol) {
          // make sure to inject `$filter` in service
          return {
            end: $filter('dateFilter')(hol.HOLIDAY_END),
            start: $filter('dateFilter')(hol.HOLIDAY_START),
            title: hol.HOLIDAY_TITLE,
            color: $filter('colorEventFilter')(hol.HOLIDAY_EVENT_STATE_ID)
          }

        });
        // return the events array to next `then()`
        return holidayEvents;

      });
    // return the `$http` promise to controller
    return requestPromise;

  };
});
```

Then in controller all you would need is

```
getUserEventsById.getUserEventsById().then(function(holidayEvents){
    $scope.eventSources[0].events = holidayEvents;
}).catch(function(){

   // do something if promise chain has a rejection
})
```

Comment: Its antipattern to do data manipulation in service... this service calls becomes obsolute coz you can't use this in other places where you want different data instead of manipulated one here... just my thoughts...

Comment: @Thalaivar if so then it's easy to set up service with more methods that can be combined within the service. Most style guides will tell you to keep controllers lean and do processing in service

Comment: @charlietfl Sorry for the late reply. Thanks for answering my question, i seem to be getting errors in my service. The `holidayEvents` array isn't getting populated?

Comment: @charlietfl I have just fixed a few formatting errors. There are no errors in the console but the events are not loading into the calendar at all? I have `console.logged` the `holidayEvents` in the controller and it all seems fine?

Comment: So data is making it to controller? And in format expected?

Comment: @charlietfl I have added an edit to my question. The service seems fine its the section in the controller.

Comment: what is `GetAllEventsByUserResult` ? need to see what `results` is when this is used. A sample of the actual data would help

Comment: @charlietfl `GetAllEventsByUserResult` is just the highest node in the JSON. I have added the JSON result into the edit.

Comment: those aren't valid date strings. Am going to create test of the service while you sort out date formatting

Comment: @charlietfl Yeah the date strings get formatted inside `$filter('dateFilter')` i have checked this and it works.

Comment: Basic service [works fine here](http://plnkr.co/edit/RYqGLft8AlD5a1qBIXCF?p=preview) ...had to remove the `$filter`'s since I don't have them

Comment: @charlietfl As my events are getting loaded into a calendar what happens if the API/Events have not yet been populated? I think this is what is happening.

Comment: @charlietfl Is there a way to wait for the response?

Comment: can run this in a router resolve so data is there when controller fires. whatever calendar module you use should accept a promise though for data

Comment: @charlietfl I'm not sure if the calendar accepts a promise. It says a JSON feed, an array or a function? http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/

Comment: are you not using angular-ui calendar? It is an angular module wrapper for fullcalendar. If not can create directive and initialize calendar inside the service promise resolve

Comment: @charlietfl I am yes, i think.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104206/discussion-between-ben-clarke-and-charlietfl).

Answer (score 0):

A better solution/approach would be to make your `api` call from `resolve`.

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .config(config);

function config($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'yourTemp.html',
            controller: 'Main',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            resolve: {
                getUserEventsById: function(getUserEventsById){
                    return getUserEventsById.getUserEventsById()
                }
            }
        });
}

angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('Main', Main);

Main.$inject = ['getUserEventsById'];
function Main(getUserEventsById) {
      var vm = this;
      vm.yourdata = getUserEventsById.data;
}
```

Now you could run your `forEach` loop on `vm.yourdata`, which would run fine.

Comment: Idea is good but still no guarantee that service request will have completed, or possibly failed. The resolve is still returning empty array because that's what service is returning regardless if request succeeds or not ...not a promise

Comment: @charlietfl: The controller won't get instantiated if you have a failed promise, the routes get rejected... else your view gets loaded and everything works as expected... resolve returns a promise... correct me if i am wrong...

Comment: There is no failed promise is the point. OP doesn't return a promise , only an empty array `return holidays;` . So that gets returned regardless if the `$http` succeeds or not. The `resolve` will never get rejected. Also if the `$http` takes 2 seconds the empty array will still end up in controller